# Error de CORS, No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angular, spring-boot, heroku, cors

Hola estoy intentando desplegar mi aplicacion SpringBoot en heroku y me a aparece el siguiente error de CORS

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://porfolioback.herokuapp.com//educacion/lista' from origin 'https://porfoliofronted.web.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
polyfills.5b5fb5c6c5b9af82.js:1          GET https://porfolioback.herokuapp.com//educacion/lista net::ERR_FAILED
```

Y el controlador de la clase educacion:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/educacion")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "https://porfoliofronted.web.app")
public class CEducacion {...
```

No logro encontrar una solucion al error

Comment: El tema es que `https://porfoliofronted.web.app` no pertenece al mismo dominio que `https://porfolioback.herokuapp.com`, por lo que por temas de seguridad no te permitira... quiza tengas que cambiar el `origins` a `https://porfolioback.herokuapp.com`

Answer (score 2):

Los dominios `porfoliofronted.web.app` y `porfolioback.herokuapp.com` son distintos, con lo que los navegadores bloquean dichas peticiones salvo que el servidor (backend) indique al cliente (frontend) que tiene permitido ese orígen cruzado.

Es decir, tu backend debe incluir en las peticiones una cabecera `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: [FRONTEND]` para que el navegador no bloquee dichas peticiones.

---

He probado a acceder al backend con `curl -v -X OPTIONS https://porfolioback.herokuapp.com//educacion/lista` y efectivamente no devuelve dicha cabecera, como debería. Prueba localmente a hacer esta petición y mira en la respuesta si las incluye, ya que puede ser problema de tu aplicación Spring.